# RecId in table less than NextVal in SystemSequences

Tags: axapta

I have a table Table1. I manually entered 2 rows and I see the recid of 2nd row as 5637144577.

But when I'm running this query:

```
select NEXTVAL FROM SYSTEMSEQUENCES WHERE DATAAREAID = 'DAT' AND NAME = 'SEQNO' 
AND TABID = (SELECT TABLEID FROM SQLDICTIONARY WHERE NAME='Table1' AND FIELDID=0)
```

I'm getting the NextVal = 5637145326

Why is there a mismatch between RecIds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an AOS inserts a record into a table, first it reserves a block of (256? I don't remember) RecId values from the SYSTEMSEQUENCES table. When all reserved and cached RecId's have been used by the AOS (i.e. that many records have been inserted in the table), it will reserve the next block of RecId's, so the NEXTVAL will be increased accordingly, not by 1 but by the number of the reserved RecId's.

It is a bit surprising that in your case it reserved such a large block (more than 749) of RecId's. Possibly you have more than 1 AOS and each AOS reserved its own block of RecId's for inserts?

Anyway, nothing to worry about, the 'mismatch' is as per design, so that AX doesn't increment NETVAL in the SYSTEMSEQUENCES table for each insert in each AX table. Caching rules.

Comment: Is there a way I can make sure the RecIds are in continuation or atleast don't duplicate if I want to insert records into a table both manually and also through SQL Server Management Studio? Is there a way to access the value from cache?

Comment: You cannot access the cached value from SQL Server. You can increase the value in the SYSTEMSEQUENCES table yourself and use your 'reserved' values when you insert table records directly from SQL Server, not from AX.